# OptionsMenu doesn`t appear

Tags: android, android-menu

I have `ListFragment` and i want manage ActionBar. However, it does not appear on the screen.
Here is code for `ListFragment`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle saved) {
    super.onCreate(saved);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    ...
}
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_crime_list, menu);
}
```

*fragment_crime_list:*

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_new_crime"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:title="@string/new_crime"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
</menu>
```

In my `manifest.xml` i have set only `minSdkVersion` but it doesnt help

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    />
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: ActionBar is hidden too?

Comment: Your activity extends whaat?

Comment: @skywall, yes, ActionBar is hidden

Comment: @hegazy, This is `ListFragment`, not an activity

Comment: The fragment is in an activity!

Comment: `extends FragmentActivity`

Comment: Replace with `extends ActionBarActivity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action bar is not added by default in your activity and it's also added in API level 11 not 8. So to add it, you have two options that I'll address here

**On API level 11 or higher**

The action bar is included in all activities that use the Theme.Holo theme (or one of its descendants), which is the default theme when either the targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion attribute is set to "11" or higher. If you don't want the action bar for an activity, set the activity theme to Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.

**API level 7 or higher**

You have to use the appcompat v7 library that you can find exactly how to add it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Adding).

Comment: I have made   `<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        />` But it has no effect

Comment: As mentioned above you need to change the activity theme to be Theme.Holo theme (or one of its descendants).
`<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">`

Answer (score 0):

For fragments you need to set`setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in your oncreatView()

Answer (score 0):

just call super constructor of onCreateOptionMenu it will work

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_sample, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```